# Pass values to route

Tags: aurelia

I have a list of items. When the user clicks on an item, the user will be taken to item details page.

I want to pass an object containing item details(like item's image URL) to the route. However, I don't want to expose it in the routes url.

If there were a way to do something like `<a route-href="route: details; settings.bind({url: item.url})">${item.name}</a>` that would be gold.

I have seen properties can be passed to a route if defined in the route configuration. However, I don't know how to change that from the template. Another way could be is to define a singleton and store the values there and inject the object to the destination route.

Is there a way to pass values to routes from view (like angular ui-routers `param` object)?

Comment: I think you should get this "image url" inside the `activate` method of the view-model

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have you looked here? https://github.com/aurelia/documentation/blob/master/English/docs.md#generating-route-urls Based on the docs, it looks like it might add that to the url, but I'm unclear about it. They have something like this in there: <a route-href="route: userDetail; params.bind: { id: user.id }">${user.name}</a>

Comment: Have a look at the Routing section of the docs http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.3/doc/article/cheat-sheet

Comment: The objective is to not pass them as url parameters. While passing objects to another route, I don't want them to be exposed in the url.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay so I figured out a way to achieve something closer to what I wanted:

**Objective**: Pass data to route without exposing them in the location bar.

Let's say, we have a list of users and we want to pass the `username` to the user's profile page without defining it as a query parameter.

In the view-model, first inject `Router` and then add data to the destination router:

```
goToUser(username) {
    let userprofile = this.router.routes.find(x => x.name === 'userprofile');
    userprofile.name = username;
    this.router.navigateToRoute('userprofile');
}
```

Now when the route changes to `userprofile`, you can access the route settings as the second parameter of `activate` method:

```
activate(params, routeData) {
    console.log(routeData.name); //user name
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what this line does?? `let userprofile = this.router.routes.find(x => x.name === 'userprofile');`

Comment: @Danny is that working? it throws error **routes of undefined**

Comment: i need to pass a array of value through router @Danny

Comment: @sibi It is working, but the problem is that the `userprofile.name` is a string and can't contain anything other than a string. There is another solution to this if you're passing in an array. Also, that error you're getting, I'm having a good guess that you're not injecting it and storing it to your class??

Comment: @danny ok, leave that array, for string, i imported and injected **Router**, and `this.theRouter.navigate()` is working fine. According to above ans, what about **routes**  `let userprofile = this.router.routes.find(x => x.name === 'userprofile');` in this line routes throws the error, as **routes of undefined**.

Comment: @sibi Sorry, I don't understand. If it's already causing an error on the routes.find part, why would `this.theRouter.navigate()` be working fine in this example?? You would need to show me your code so I can see exactly what you're doing. You can't just import and inject it, you need to store it somewhere in this example.

Comment: Works like a charm here. Thumbs up! I was able to assign it a number but when the page received it, it was converted to a string. No biggie.

Answer (score 3):

For those @Sayem's answer didn't worked, you can put any additional data (even objects) into setting property like this:

```
let editEmployeeRoute = this.router.routes.find(x => x.name === 'employees/edit');
editEmployeeRoute.settings.editObject = employeeToEdit;
this.router.navigateToRoute('employees/edit', {id: employeeToEdit.id});
```

So editObject will be delivered on the other side:

```
activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
    console.log(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction);
    this.editId = params.id;
    this.editObject = routeConfig.settings.editObject;
}
```

hopes this helps others encountering same problem as me. TG.

Comment: I am pretty new to Aurelia, so I cannot say anything about the period 2015/2016 from which @sayem's original question and answer originate, but after reading the Aurelia docs and forum, I assume that your solution is nowadays the right way to go.